# Javascript: how to keep Solace the session alive

Tags: javascript, angular, session, solace

I have a website the use Angular and a Solace system that manage the communication between the Front-end and Back-end site.

Here my configuration for it:

[image]

As you can see, the `keepAliveIntervalInMsecs` is 30000ms and `keepAliveIntervalsLimit` is 100. That's total 3000s. But if I pause the browser with a breakpoint for debugging for 30s, the session is disconnected and I have to reconnect it. This is a huge problem on any page that have real-time data because it break the subscription.

So, how can I keep the session alive for longer?

Answer (score 1):

The keepAliveIntervalInMsecs and keepAliveIntervalsLimit properties are useful for controlling the application side keep-alive values. With web messaging, there is another timeout value on the broker side that you should also adjust. This is in the client-profile for your client and is called web-transport inactive-timeout.

Comment: Are there any other way to address this without touching the broker side. Like, spawning a session in web worker and let it run?